# Классы и математические операции в них

Tags: python, методы, класс

Задача Создайте класс «Дробь». Необходимо хранить в полях класса: числитель и знаменатель. Реализуйте методы класса для ввода данных, вывода данных, реализуйте доступ к отдельным полям через методы класса. Также создайте методы класса для выполнения арифметических операций (сложение, вычитание, умножение, деление, и т.д.).
Попытка написать код (гарантированно не правильная). Как правильно не понимаю

```
class Fraction():
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.numerator = a
        self.denominator = b
        self.result = c


    def fraction(a, b):
        if 0 < b:
            print(a / b)
        else:
            print("Erorr")

    def addition(a, b, i, c):
        if 0 < i:
            c = (a/b) + i
            return c


AB = Fraction (15, 7, 4)
print(AB.addition())
```

Comment: какието произвольные буквы в коде, как будто наугад вырваны откуда-то ещё для видимости попытки решения..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Fraction():
    def __init__(self, numerator, denominator):
        self.numerator = numerator
        self.denominator = denominator
        self.canonize()
    
    @staticmethod
    def fromstr(string):
        return Fraction( * (int(i.strip()) for i in string.split('/')))
    
    def canonize(self):
        def gcd(a,b):
            while a != 0 and b != 0:
                if a > b:
                    a %= b
                else:
                    b %= a
            return a+b
        
        g = gcd(self.numerator, self.denominator)
        self.numerator //= g
        self.denominator //= g
        
    def __float__(self):
        return self.numerator / self.denominator
        
    def __trunc__(self):
        return self.numerator // self.denominator
        
    def __int__(self):
        return self.__trunc__()
        
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.numerator}/{self.denominator}"
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Fraction({str(self)})"
        
    def __round__(self, ndigits=None, /):
        return round(float(self), ndigits)
        
    def __add__(self, value):
        return Fraction(
            self.numerator*value.denominator + value.numerator*self.denominator,
            self.denominator*value.denominator
            )
        
    def __mul__(self, value):
        return Fraction(
            self.numerator*value.numerator,
            self.denominator*value.denominator
            )
        
    def __neg__(self):
        return Fraction(
            -self.numerator,
            self.denominator
            )
        
    def __sub__(self, value, /):
        return Fraction(
            self.numerator*value.denominator - value.numerator*self.denominator,
            self.denominator*value.denominator
            )
        
    def __truediv__(self, value):
        return Fraction(
            self.numerator*value.denominator,
            self.denominator*value.numerator
            )
        
        
print( Fraction(5,7)/Fraction(1,5) + Fraction(7,11)*Fraction(11,7) )


print(Fraction.fromstr(input()))
```

Comment: Скорее всего не примут, нет проверки деления на ноль, а это же главное в дробях ))) При вводе `53/0` получаем `1/0`

Comment: что впринципе эквивалентно)
Смотря куда сдавать. В школе на ноль делить нельзя, а в универе 1/0 это особое число (ещё 0/0), которое имеет свой смысл.

Comment: Не примут скорее всего по другой причине ;) не вкурсе программы обучения, но редко где проходят перегрузку операторов.

Comment: но и проверку на ноль можно добавить тривиально

Comment: Согласен. Но 1/0 и 0/0 - это не числа, а неопределенности. Основная проблема в том, что ноль считают числом - а по сути это ничто )))

Comment: Вроде класс продолжает работать математически правильно, а при касте к float или int выйдет zerodivisionerror - потому так и оставил. - не баг, а фича )))

Comment: Откуда на стаке могут баги взяться? Только фичи )))

Comment: как раз приняли, так как на следующей за заданием лекции, эту тему и разбирали

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант. Попробуйте:

```
class Fraction():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.numerator = a
        self.denominator = b
#        self.result = c

    def _input(self):
        try:
            a = int(input("\nВведите новое значение для 'a': "))
            self.numerator = a
            b = int(input("Введите новое значение для 'b': "))
            self.denominator = b
            rezult = f"a = {a}, b = {b}"
        except:
            rezult = "Erorr"
        return rezult    

    def _fraction(self):
        if self.denominator:
            rezult = self.numerator / self.denominator
        else:
            rezult = "Erorr"
        return rezult

    def addition(self, i=0):
        if 0 <= i and self.denominator:
            rezult = (self.numerator / self.denominator) + i
            return rezult

#                     a  b
fraction = Fraction (15, 7)
print(f'\naddition()  : {fraction.addition():>10.5f}')
print(f'addition(12): {fraction.addition(12):>10.5f}')

print(f'_fraction() : {fraction._fraction():>10.5f}')

print(f'\n_input()    : {fraction._input()}')
print(f'_fraction   : {fraction._fraction():>10.5f}')
```